# Changing DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform an AJAX request to change DOM. have this HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s12 l6">
    <input type="date" class="date datepicker" name="date" required>
    <label for="date">Date</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s12 l6 hour">
    <select class="select-hour" name="time">
        <option value=""selected>No options available</option>
    </select>
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

And this is my JS:

```
$(".date").change(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/reserve }}',
        data: {
            date: $(this).val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var selectDropdown = $(this).parent().next().find('select').empty();
            selectDropdown.append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

When I receive the options from the server I want to append them in the select but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is in the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that, `this` isn't the same on the `function(e){ ... }` and `success: function (data) { ... }`.

[See scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

```
$(".date").change(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/reserve }}',
        data: {
            date: $this.val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var selectDropdown = $this.parent().next().find('select').empty();
            selectDropdown.append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!!